# NPE в самом начале изучения Java

Tags: java

Словил `NullPointerException` в ходе выполнения программы.

Ловит ошибку на строке `products[i].getTitle()` в методе `output`.

Скорее всего где-то ошибся с ссылками и передачей массива.

Подскажите пожалуйста где возможна проблема.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Deal deal = input();
        output(deal);
}


public static Deal input(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Введите имя покупателя");
    String buyerName = sc.next();
    Party buyer = new Party();
    buyer.setName(buyerName);
    System.out.println("Введите имя продавца");
    String sellerName = sc.next();
    Party seller = new Party();
    seller.setName(sellerName);
    Product[] products = new Product[3];
    for(Product i : products){
        i=inputProduct();
    }
    Deal deal = new Deal(buyer, seller, products);
    return deal;

}   
public static Product inputProduct(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Введите описание продукта");
    String title=sc.next();
    System.out.println("Введите цену продукта");
    double price=sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Введите количество продукта");
    int quantity=sc.nextInt();
    Product product = new Product();
    product.setPrice(price);
    product.setTitle(title);
    product.setQuantity(quantity);
    return product;

}
public static void output(Deal deal){
    String nameOfSeller=deal.getSeller().getName();
    String nameOfBuyer=deal.getBuyer().getName();
    Product[] products=deal.getProducts();
    System.out.println("Deal "
            +deal.getDate()
            +" Имя продавца "
            +nameOfSeller
            +" Имя покупателя "
            +nameOfBuyer
            +":");
    for(int i=0; i<products.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Product "
            +products[i].getTitle()
            +" Цена "
            +products[i].getPrice()
            +" Количество "
            +products[i].getQuantity()
            +" Общая цена за продукт "
            +products[i].getCost());
    }
    System.out.println("Общая стоимость сделки "+deal.getSum());
}
}


public class Party {

private String name;

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }
}

public class Product {
private String title;
private double price;
private int quantity;
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}
public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}
public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}
public double getCost(){
    return this.price*this.quantity;
}
}
import java.util.Date;

public class Deal {
private Date date;
private Party buyer;
private Party seller;
private Product[] products;

    public Deal(Party buyer,Party seller,Product[] products){
        this.date=new Date();
        this.buyer=buyer;
        this.seller=seller;
        this.products=products;
    }
    public double getSum(){
        double rezult=0;
        for(Product i: this.products){
            rezult+=i.getCost();
        }
        return rezult;
        }
    public Party getBuyer(){
        return this.buyer;
    }
    public Party getSeller(){
        return this.seller;
    }
    public Date getDate(){
        return this.date;
    }
    public Product[] getProducts(){
        return this.products;

    }

}
```

Comment: Не стоит такие большие программы в вопросы помещать. Воспроизведите свою проблему в упрощенной версии своей программы, выбросив из нее всё, что не относится к вашему вопросу, ее и выкладывайте. Почитайте http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: И где вы её словили, ни одного catch в програме не нашёл.

Comment: Словил это не в плане использования конструкций try\catch, а вообще наличие ошибки. Немного невнятно формулирую вопрос)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В методе `input(...)`, а конкретно, вот в этом фрагменте:

```
for(Product i : products){
    i = inputProduct();
}
```

`i` – локальная переменная цикла, изменение которой не приводит к изменению переменной в массиве. Циклы в стиле `for each` не предназначены для изменения данных.

Решением будет использование обычного цикла `for`:

```
for(int i=0; i<products.length; i++){
    products[i] = inputProduct();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, проблема была решена)

Answer (score 1):

> `for(Product i : products){
>     i = inputProduct();
>   }`

Этот код эквивалентен такому

```
for(idx = 0; idx < products.length; idx++){
    Product i;
    i = products[idx];
    i = inputProduct();
}
```

А должно быть так

```
for(idx = 0; idx < products.length; idx++){
    Product i;
    i = inputProduct();
    products[idx] = i;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)